# tfs build craeting wrong AppManifest.xaml

Tags: msbuild, silverlight-3.0

I created a automated build in tfs for the silverlight project. my project uses prism and so it has many xap created. but the AppManifest.xaml in the main xap file is wrong. it is using AppManifest.xaml of some other module(XAP file). Can anyone explain why this wil happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probelm is, as the silverlight projects in the solution are building randomly, so it picks the manifest.xml of the project which is currently building and create a xap file.
So the solution is creating dependencies between sivelright projects. so that it will build in a certain order and there will not be any confusion of manifest

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an MS BUILD configuration issue.  Can you post your .proj file?  I am guessing you have something configured incorrectly- that is the only way this would happen.